# Matlab How to assign values on non-diagonal matrix

Tags: matlab

I have a matrix called "C" with 5x5 dimension, and i want to put 3 formulas (first formula where I have 0 (on diagonal, the second one where I have 1 and the third one where I have 2)

```
0 1 1 1 1
2 0 1 1 1
2 2 0 1 1
2 2 2 0 1
2 2 2 2 0
```

The above notation is just to know where I want to put the formula.

For diagonal it works with:

```
C(logical(eye(size(C)))) = V
```

where V is my formula.

Comment: What are these formulas? Could you provide an example that includes what should be assigned?

Comment: It's not important what is the formula, for exemple how can assign a value.  `tril(C, -1)=5`, it doesn't work

Comment: try `C(tril(true(size(C)),-1))=5`

Comment: Yes, It work, but for above how can i assign values?

Comment: @Marius sorry for late replay you can use 1 and 2 instead of 5 and `triu` for upper triangle

Comment: It works with `C(logical(triu(ones(size(C)),1))) = 6`

Comment: Thank you for your help!